# Accessing files in python: extra spaces

Tags: python, file, spaces

My code looks like this:

```
fileName = "interview.txt"
accessMode = "r"
interview = open(fileName, accessMode)

name = interview.readline()
age = interview.readline()
colour = interview.readline()
print("Hello, "+name+" who is "+age+" years old and who's favourite colour is "+colour+".")
```

I want it to say: Hello *name* who is *age* years old and who's favourite colour is *colour*. Instead, as I had to put the information on different lines when recording the info (from a different python program) I put a \n afterwards. So the output has an enter afterwards like so:

```
 Hello, *Name*
 who is *age*
 years old and who's favourite colour is *colour*.
```

Comment: Simplest:  `interview.readline().strip()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call strip on the readline output:

```
interview.readline().strip()
```

Comment: It would be better to use `rstrip`.

Comment: @zondo I used to think the same thing until I realized I was going back and changing them all the time when I got unexpected input. Now I assume if you've used one of the directional variants that you really meant it for some reason, so that's the only time I'd use one anymore.

Comment: When do you get unexpected input?

Comment: @zondo when someone changes it or does anything I wasn't expecting, so all the time :)  The point I'm trying to make is that it's better to be defensive than to end up with bad data that you have to fix because the tiny amount of extra time the computer spends stripping nothing costs much less.